# AutoMapper Enum to byte with implemention IMapperConfigurator

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, automapper

Enum definition is

```
public enum RowStatusEnum
{
    Modified = 1,
    Removed = 2,
    Added = 3
}

public class RowStatusEnumConvertor : IMapperConfigurator
{
    public void Cofigure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<RowStatusEnum, byte>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<byte, RowStatusEnum >();
    }
}
```

I config autoMapper with Implemention IMapperConfigurator in RowStatusEnumConvertor class, 
but not work this code and not map this type, i think my config not correct or not enough, 
please help me

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have reproduced your problem. The solution is pretty simple, don't configure AutoMapper and set the base type of the enum to byte. Like this:

```
public enum RowStatusEnum : byte
{
   Modified = 1,
   Removed = 2,
   Added = 3,
}
```

To let it work:

```
byte x = 3;
RowStatusEnum rowStatus = Mapper.Map<RowStatusEnum>(x); 
//The result will be: Added
```

Comment: i want config this convert in IMapperConfigurator and use from in all place of project without reconfig again

Answer (score 36):

Will something like this work for you?

**Classes.cs**

```cs
namespace StackOverflow.RowStatus
{
    public enum RowStatusEnum
    {
        Modified = 1,
        Removed = 2,
        Added = 3
    }
}
```

**AutoMapperConfigurator.cs**

```cs
namespace StackOverflow.RowStatus
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

    using AutoMapper;

    public class MyProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<byte, RowStatusEnum>().ConvertUsing(
                x => Enum.GetValues(typeof(RowStatusEnum))
                         .Cast<RowStatusEnum>().First(y => (byte)y == x));
            Mapper.CreateMap<RowStatusEnum, byte>().ConvertUsing(
                x => (byte)x);
        }
    }
}
```

**MappingTests.cs**

```cs
namespace StackOverflow.RowStatus
{
    using AutoMapper;

    using NUnit.Framework;

    [TestFixture]
    public class MappingTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void AutoMapper_Configuration_IsValid()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }

        [TestCase(1, Result = RowStatusEnum.Modified)]
        [TestCase(2, Result = RowStatusEnum.Removed)]
        [TestCase(3, Result = RowStatusEnum.Added)]
        public RowStatusEnum AutoMapper_ConvertFromByte_IsValid(
                                                   byte rowStatusEnum)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            return Mapper.Map<byte, RowStatusEnum>(rowStatusEnum);
        }

        [TestCase(RowStatusEnum.Modified, Result = 1)]
        [TestCase(RowStatusEnum.Removed, Result = 2)]
        [TestCase(RowStatusEnum.Added, Result = 3)]
        public byte AutoMapper_ConvertFromEnum_IsValid(
                                                   RowStatusEnum rowStatusEnum)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            return Mapper.Map<RowStatusEnum, byte>(rowStatusEnum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The following lines are key points :) 
Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

Thanks Mightymuke

Comment: Short version also seems to work: ```Mapper.CreateMap<byte, RowStatusEnum().ConvertUsing(x => (RowStatusEnum)x);```

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Answer (score 24):

Starting from version `9` of Automapper there were changes in initialization which caused to be out of date above examples. I updated above example and left original values to have also reference to older version (NUnit `3.12.0`):

**RowStatusEnum**

```cs
namespace StackOverflow.RowStatus
{
    public enum RowStatusEnum
    {
        Modified = 1,
        Removed = 2,
        Added = 3
    }
}
```

**AutoMapperConfigurator.cs**

```cs
namespace StackOverflow.RowStatus
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

    using AutoMapper;

    public class MyProfile : Profile
    {
        public MyProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<byte, RowStatusEnum>().ConvertUsing(
                x => Enum.GetValues(typeof(RowStatusEnum))
                    .Cast<RowStatusEnum>().First(y => (byte)y == x));
            CreateMap<RowStatusEnum, byte>().ConvertUsing(
                x => (byte)x);
        }
    }
}
```

**MappingTests**

```cs
namespace StackOverflow.RowStatus
{
    using AutoMapper;

    using NUnit.Framework;

    [TestFixture]
    public class MappingTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void AutoMapper_Configuration_IsValid()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }

        [TestCase(1, ExpectedResult = RowStatusEnum.Modified)]
        [TestCase(2, ExpectedResult = RowStatusEnum.Removed)]
        [TestCase(3, ExpectedResult = RowStatusEnum.Added)]
        public RowStatusEnum AutoMapper_ConvertFromByte_IsValid(
            byte rowStatusEnum)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            return mapper.Map<byte, RowStatusEnum>(rowStatusEnum);
        }

        [TestCase(RowStatusEnum.Modified, ExpectedResult = 1)]
        [TestCase(RowStatusEnum.Removed, ExpectedResult = 2)]
        [TestCase(RowStatusEnum.Added, ExpectedResult = 3)]
        public byte AutoMapper_ConvertFromEnum_IsValid(
            RowStatusEnum rowStatusEnum)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            return mapper.Map<RowStatusEnum, byte>(rowStatusEnum);
        }
    }
}
```