# Unit test the Automapper profiles

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper

**I do want** to test the custom logic in the `CreateMap` method. I do **NOT** want to test whether the mapping exist at all for some types.

How can I do that or what are the classes that I need to know. I am grateful for every hint The document about. Automapper unit testing seems very rare...

```
public class UnitProfile : Profile
{
   protected override void Configure()
   {
      // Here I create my maps with custom logic that needs to be tested

    CreateMap<Unit, UnitTreeViewModel>()
         .ForMember(dest => dest.IsFolder, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.UnitTypeState == UnitType.Folder ? true : false));

    CreateMap<CreateUnitViewModel, Unit>()
         .ForMember(dest => dest.UnitTypeState, o => o.MapFrom(src => (UnitType)Enum.ToObject(typeof(UnitType), src.SelectedFolderTypeId)));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is the documentation for configuration testing: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html

You can see an example of it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150006/1505426

Comment: I'm missing something. Why can't you write a unit test that creates an instance of `Unit`, maps it to `UnitTreeViewModel`, and asserts that the mapped object is what you expect?

Comment: Thats a good question. I guess that was due to nearly midnight on my side ;-)

Comment: ok I got it: Mapper.AddProfile(new UnitProfile()); now all works fine :)

Answer (score 31):

An example of tests for Automapper profile (I used Automapper in version `10.0.0` amd NUnit in version `3.12.0`):

**RowStatusEnum**

```cs
namespace StackOverflow.RowStatus
{
    public enum RowStatusEnum
    {
        Modified = 1,
        Removed = 2,
        Added = 3
    }
}
```

**MyProfile**

```cs
namespace StackOverflow.RowStatus
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

    using AutoMapper;

    public class MyProfile : Profile
    {
        public MyProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<byte, RowStatusEnum>().ConvertUsing(
                x => Enum.GetValues(typeof(RowStatusEnum))
                    .Cast<RowStatusEnum>().First(y => (byte)y == x));
            CreateMap<RowStatusEnum, byte>().ConvertUsing(
                x => (byte)x);
        }
    }
}
```

**MappingTests**

```cs
namespace StackOverflow.RowStatus
{
    using AutoMapper;

    using NUnit.Framework;

    [TestFixture]
    public class MappingTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void AutoMapper_Configuration_IsValid()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }

        [TestCase(1, ExpectedResult = RowStatusEnum.Modified)]
        [TestCase(2, ExpectedResult = RowStatusEnum.Removed)]
        [TestCase(3, ExpectedResult = RowStatusEnum.Added)]
        public RowStatusEnum AutoMapper_ConvertFromByte_IsValid(
            byte rowStatusEnum)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            return mapper.Map<byte, RowStatusEnum>(rowStatusEnum);
        }

        [TestCase(RowStatusEnum.Modified, ExpectedResult = 1)]
        [TestCase(RowStatusEnum.Removed, ExpectedResult = 2)]
        [TestCase(RowStatusEnum.Added, ExpectedResult = 3)]
        public byte AutoMapper_ConvertFromEnum_IsValid(
            RowStatusEnum rowStatusEnum)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            return mapper.Map<RowStatusEnum, byte>(rowStatusEnum);
        }
    }
}
```